# What can cause clock line to have EMI emmisions?

Tags: pcb, clock, emc

I am trying to understand the topic of EM radiation and EM absorption of PCB clock signal. I think the clock signal is given more important than others since it is toggling all the time.

So since a clock signal has a source and destination, the current will have a way to return to GND. The clock line is not floating. How can it still have EM emissions under any circumstances? I mean, the signal travels on PCB track and returns to the reference plane of the PCB. Why should there be a possibility of radiating emissions that can cause to fail EMC test?

A clock signal could be sandwitched between other copper planes in the PCB layer stack, or it could be on the top or bottom layer. In case it is top or bottom layer, it could absorb EM radiation from other sources since changing electric/magnetic field always induces a voltage in a conductor. But, even if the clock signal absorbs a tiny amount of EM emissions (relative to power of clock oscillator IC) from elsewhere, can it really cause the signal to be come corrupted? I mean, why is this so important that it would need to be investigated?

Comment: "I mean, the signal travels on PCB track and returns to the reference plane"  The signal and return path are not the same.  The signal is in a different place in the universe than the ground plane.  You could put a resistor on the output of what makes the signal.  This will reduce the power in the trace.  The EM radiation might not be coming from the clock but from another circuit that is connected to the clock.

Comment: How familiar are you with antenna and wave/field concepts? For example if I say a microstrip trace has some overall dipole characteristic at a distance, is that enough of a clue to get you going?

Comment: All I know is that we have a twisted pair wire and we leave the two ends floating, we get an antenna. This is called a di-pole anetnna. Maybe you could refer me to an application note.